# No .git folder but git status still returns

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using CodeIgniter to create an app. There is no .git folder in the project anywhere, but the project is initiliazed since `git status` returns this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../../../Vagrantfile

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How is this even possible? There is no .git folder anywhere. This is what `ls -la` returns:

```
total 124
drwxrwxr-x  7 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  7 11:18 .
drwxrwxr-x  8 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  7 11:25 ..
drwx------ 14 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  7 10:04 application
drwxrwxr-x  6 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  7 10:36 assets
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username   557 Jan  9 14:32 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username  6504 Jan  9 14:32 contributing.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username   302 Jan  9 14:32 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username   365 Mar  7 11:18 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  7 11:28 .idea
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_username my_username 10253 Jan  9 14:32 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username  1114 Jan  9 14:32 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 my_username my_username  2353 Jan  9 14:32 readme.rst
drwx------  8 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  6 15:07 system
drwx------  8 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  6 15:07 system
drwx------ 14 my_username my_username  4096 Mar  6 15:07 user_guide
```

Running Ubuntu 16.04 if that makes any difference.

I've clearly made a mistake somewhere, but I'm not experience enough with git or CodeIgniter to figure out what's a fault. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `../../../` suggests the root of the repository is (at least) a few steps up the directory tree. What does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` show?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Biffen. `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` shows `/home/my_username/dev`.

Comment: And is there perhaps a `/home/my_username/dev/.git` directory?

Comment: There is. It contains the VagrantFile that is used to host all my projects. But there is a .gitignore in there that states that anything inside the project folder should be ignore: `public/projects/*.` That way each project can have it's own .git folder.
`

Comment: You're clearly lacking some basic understanding of Git. I don't know where to start, except recommend that you read a book or tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my ineptitude in such a subtle way. I've found a work-around, commented in @Hammerstad's reply.

Comment: Even though it’s ignored, `git` still considers it part of the same repository. It’s possible to create a repository inside a directory managed by another repository (which it is even with `.gitignore`), which appears to be what you did, but it might cause problems later on in the “outer” repository. It would be easier to put the `Vagrantfile` in a subdirectory, make that a repository, and put a symlink to that new repository.

Answer (score 5):

Considering git tracks files inside a folder, and all its subfolders - and the Vagrantfile (which is modified) is located three folders up, it is likely that your .git folder is located three folders up.

You can check this, by asking git where the rootfolder of your project is:

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think what I did was when I initialized the project in git I ran `git add *` instead of `git add .`. I'm not sure if this was the cause of the problem. My solution (work-around) was to create a new directory, move everything into that, run `git init` inside there (in a new repo), commit all the project files and push everything. Then I deleted the old repo that was causing issues.

Comment: @mohnjatthews since you have solve the problem, you can write it as an answer, and mark it 24 hours later.

Answer (score 0):

## This solution isn't ideal, and is more of a work around.

Other users have suggested I take a closer look at how Git works. If you are having the same issue as I had, it is probably best that you also read up on Git.

---

### Solution (Workaround)

- Create a new directory outside of the current path.

  - If you're having the problem in `~/dev/projects/this_project` create a new directory in `~/Documents/projects/this_project`.
- Copy everything from your problem directory (in my case `~/dev/projects/this_project`) to the new directory (in my case `~/Documents/projects/this_project`).
- Create a new repository in Github / Gitlab / Bitbucket / whatever you use
- Add existing project to your Git repository.

  - `git init`
  - `git add .`
  - `git commit -m "Moved from problem repository."`
  - `git remote add origin remote https://github.com/username/your_project.git`
  - `git remote -v`
  - `git push origin master`
- Delete the problem directory (`rm -rf ~/dev/projects/this_project`)
- Move the new directory to the problem directory's location (`mv ~/Documents/projects/this_project ~/dev/projects/this_project`)
- Done.

---

Like I said this is a work around that happened to work for me, not a solution. Good luck.